# How to prevent browser caching for a specific page that needs POST data?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching

I am new to browser caching. I have following codes in my .htaccess file:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

I have few web pages that require POST data to be displayed. I don't want text/html response to be cached for these pages. It is ok if it caches images, css and javascript. How can I achieve that through .htaccess?

Comment: you can add a simple url paramater e.g `?has_post=1` (every time you post data) and let apache not cache the page if it has a query_string (which already happens if i'm not mistaken), else you would have to bypass caching for whole page whether has post_data or not (e.g by explicitly adding an entry for this pag in `.htaccess`)

Comment: how can I bypass caching text/html response specifically for a single page through .htaccess? Can you help me with a code if that page is www.xyz.com/nocache.php

Comment: try using this `www.xyz.com/nocache.php?no_cache=1` if a url has a query_string (e.g `?no_cache=1`)  then it is not cached by the browser, but requested again